# How to list ec2 instance using aws cli

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

How can I get the list of amazon ec2 instance using aws command line tool? I checked various available commands but could not fount one suitable for this purpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=instance-state-code,Values=16"
```

Valid values for this filter:

```
The valid values are: 0 (pending), 16 (running), 32 (shutting-down), 48 (terminated), 64 (stopping), and 80 (stopped).
```

Sourced from the CLI docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html

Answer (score 3):

classic ec2 client:

```
  $ ec2-describe-instances
```

it has billions of filters, well more than 10.

current awscli

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instances
```

Comment: FYI, the classic AWS tools are going the way of the dodo - we should be recommending to people that they use awscli now.